# How to inject service to the factory class / Java

Tags: java, spring, if-statement, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

Hi I was wondering what if Addition() has some variable. Let's say Addition(SomeService service). How to inject it in this example?

```
public class OperatorFactory {
    static Map<String, Operation> operationMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        operationMap.put("add", new Addition());
        operationMap.put("divide", new Division());
        // more operators
    }

    public static Optional<Operation> getOperation(String operator) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(operationMap.get(operator));
    }
}
```

I took it from here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-replace-if-statements

I am trying to replace my "ifology" to what's above but when I inject something it is always null. For instance:

```
    public class OperatorFactory {
        private static SomeService service;
        static Map<String, Operation> operationMap = new HashMap<>();
        static {
            operationMap.put("add", new Addition(service));
            operationMap.put("divide", new Division());
            // more operators
        }

        public static Optional<Operation> getOperation(String operator {
            return Optional.ofNullable(operationMap.get(operator));
        }
    }
```

service is always null...

Comment: You never initialize service so it's always null.

Comment: Do you mean by @Autowired?

Answer (score 0):

Your design is poor.

You should make Addition and Division independent services (@Service) and thus, they can take whatever dependencies are needed in their constructors (auto-wired) and can be injected anywhere.

Your factory class would also be a service (@Service) and would consume whatever beans it wants to know about in its autowired constructor.

Managing dependency chains manually is a rabbit hole you don't want to go down.